# Windows Use Robocopy to copy all files except .sas7bdat

Tags: windows, robocopy

I know that if using robocopy to copy only files of type .sas7bdat I would use the following code,

```
ROBOCOPY C:\source C:\destination *.sas7bdat /E
```

How can I reverse this to copy all file types except .sas7bdat ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for the `/xf` flag.

Change the command to `ROBOCOPY C:\source C:\destination /xf *.sas7bdat /E` to exclude all files that are matched by the pattern that follows `/xf`.

I did a quick test of this and adding the flag meant that all files that did not match `*.sad7bdat` were copied to the destination folder.